# Python Functions, if statement not working

Tags: python, function, variables

## Number guessing game

#### (With levels)

I'm having a problem that when I put in my number to guess, it doesn't show the custom messages that I wanted to show when a player gets it wrong, while trying to fix it, it doesn't loop when you get it wrong so it just goes to the regular python console. I cant really show an error message or anything since it doesn't give one. (also I'm a bit new to python so please don't get mad if I did something really obvious)

```
import random
import time
global losses
hidden1 = random.randrange(1, 21)
hidden2 = random.randrange(1, 51)
hidden3 = random.randrange(1, 201)
losses = 0
level = 1
def goback():
  if level == 1:
    level1()
  elif level == 2:
    level2()
  elif level3 == 3:
    level3()
  else:
    print ("How?")

def meanrobot():
  if losses == 1:
    print("Its okay, try again...")
    time.sleep(1)
    goback()
  elif losses == 2:
    print("Keep trying...")
    time.sleep(1)
    goback()
  elif losses == 3:
    print("Come on, even I could have done better.")
    time.sleep(1)
    goback()
  elif losses == 4:
    print("I cant believe we're still at this.")
    time.sleep(1)
    goback()
  elif losses == 5:
    print("Great perseveration.")
    time.sleep(1)
    goback()
  elif losses == 6:
    print("I would have quit by now...")
    time.sleep(1)
    goback()
  elif losses == 7:
    print("I.. believe in you?")
    time.sleep(1)
    goback()
  elif losses == 8:
    print("My grandma could play this better than you.")
    time.sleep(1)
    goback()
  elif losses == 9:
    print("All of these bad guesses are taking up too much memory.")
    time.sleep(1)
    goback()
  elif losses == 10:
    print("Are you done yet?")
    time.sleep(1)
    goback()
  elif losses == 11:
    print("Wake me up when you have given up...")
    time.sleep(1)
    goback()

def level3():
  guess = int(input("Please enter your guess: "))
 
  if guess == hidden3:
      print ("Hit!")
      losses == 0
      level4()
  elif guess < hidden3:
      print ("Your guess is too low")
      losses3 == losses+1
      meanrobot()
  else:
      print ("Your guess is too high")
      losses == losses+1
      meanrobot()

def level2():
  guess = int(input("Please enter your guess: "))
 
  if guess == hidden2:
      print ("Hit!")
      losses == 0
      level3()
  elif guess < hidden2:
      print ("Your guess is too low")
      meanrobot()
  else:
      print ("Your guess is too high")
      meanrobot()
  meanrobot()
def level1():
  guess = int(input("Please enter your guess : "))
 
  if guess == hidden1:
      print ("Hit!")
      losses == 0
      level == level+1
      level2()
  elif guess < hidden1:
      print ("Your guess is too low")
      losses == losses+1
      meanrobot()
  else:
      print ("Your guess is too high")
      losses == losses+1
      meanrobot()

level1()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> losses == losses+1

== is an operator that return True or False. 1==0 is False, 1==1 is True.
If you want to increase losses by 1, you should do

```
losses = losses + 1
```

or

```
losses += 1
```

Comment: Thank you, its coming up with a new error now but I will try to fix it myself.

Answer (score 0):

You keep assigning variables using `var == var + 1` and that probably messes things up.
Use a single = instead